# What layout item should I use for search results?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to create a simple layout. Search textbox on top and a container with results below. A single result contains several pieces of information which I would like to display in a 'good looking' way (different colors, different size of fonts, etc). In other words I need something that you call a partial in web apps.

It also would be very nice to scroll only the results so that search textbox would always be visible and accessible.

Can you give me some hints what I should use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
<LinearLayout anroid:orientation="vertical">
   <EditText  android:layout_height="rap_content" />
   <ListView />
</LinearLayout>
```

For your result element simple implement your own `Adapter` to customize and show all the information of a result with various colors, text size etc.

Answer (score 0):

Look into the `ListView` class and `ListView.FixedViewInfo`. You would be setting the textbox as fixed and allowing all the others to scroll. If that doesn't work, I would try setting two `Fragment`s, one with a text box, and one populated with `ListView`s.